# Getting a 500 internal server error when implementing interface

Tags: php, interface

I'm writing some dummy code to learn some design patterns. Therefore I made a class `Duck.php` that implements `FlyBehavior`. When I call the `index.php`, I see a blank page, and the console tells me, there is a `500 Internal Server Error`. If I outcomment `implenets FlyBehavior`, the error disappears. So I guess I'm missing something about how to correctly implement an interface.
Thank you!

PHP 5.4.10

`Duck.php`

```
<?php
class Duck implements FlyBehavior
{

public function flyWithWings(){
      echo 'foo';
    }
}
```

`FlyBehavior.php`

```
<?php
interface FlyBehavior {
  public function flyWithWings();
}
```

`index.php`

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
include 'Duck.php';

$duck = new Duck();
echo '<br>Test';
```

Comment: Check if `Duck.php` is in the same directory. Code is working fine when everything is put together. https://eval.in/143641

Comment: You have to include `FlyBehavior.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't include the interface in the class that implements it, you can do that by `require_once`

Or an alternate to this is to use dependency management , for example check [composer](https://getcomposer.org)

```
<?php
require_once('FlyBehaviour.php');

class Duck implements FlyBehavior
{

public function flyWithWings(){
      echo 'foo';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: -.- Thanks, that was really to obvious for me to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you hate having to `require`/`include` all the class library every time manually - like I do; perhaps `__autoload` may be of interest to you:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

Setup your scripts like this:

```
/ index.php
/ libs / FlyBehavior.php
/ libs / Duck.php
```

*I.e. place all your classes in a folder called `libs` and then setup audoloader on index.php*

So, your **index.php** will look like this:

```
<?php

// Constants
define('CWD', getcwd());

// Register Autoloader 
if (!function_exists('classAutoLoader')) {
    function classAutoLoader($class) {
        $classFile = CWD .'/libs/'. $class .'.php';
        if (is_file($classFile) && !class_exists($class))
            require_once $classFile;
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('classAutoLoader');

// Rest if your script
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_error', 'On');

// Test
$duck = new Duck();
$duck->flyWithWings();

?>
```

Now, all the required classes are automatically loaded (when you instantiate them for the first time) - meaning you don't have to require any of the class files manually in your script.

Try it out; will save you tons of time :)